# How to convert DateTime in UTC format?

Tags: php, datetime

I have time in this format and I want to convert this into `UTC` timezone.

```
 : "2015-03-17T07:46:52+0100"
 : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

I am using Codeigniter framework.

Comment: you want to convert in UTC 0 means in universal time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty straightforward using DateTime objects

```
$string = "2015-03-17T07:46:52+0100";
$dt = new DateTime($string);
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the [getTimezone and setTimezone,](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimezone.php) see the example

(But this does use a Class)

UPDATE:

Without any classes you could try something like this:

```
$the_date = strtotime("2015-03-17T07:46:52+0100");
echo(date_default_timezone_get() . "<br />");
echo(date("Y-d-mTG:i:sz",$the_date) . "<br />");
echo(date_default_timezone_set("UTC") . "<br />");
echo(date("Y-d-mTG:i:sz", $the_date) . "<br />");
```